# Whats your favorite HTML/CSS "<select>" replacement object?

Tags: html, css, select, listbox

Looking for a object (CSS/Javascript) like jQueryUI controls that can be used instead of the standard HTML version;

```
<select rows="10">
<option value="1">Number One</option>
<option value="2">Number Two</option>
</select>
```

Some people write their own I have seen, but there must be some standard open source projects out there that already as this, or maybe there are not...?

Comment: My suggestion is you don't replace it at all, even if it degrades gracefully. Style it as far as you can, but please don't use JavaScript for it.

Comment: Why would you do this? There's a standard. It does well defined things. Why break that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime clients demand some graphically enhanced version of a `<select>`. I believe the "best" solution is to use an styled absolutely-positioned unordered list (at least it is semantic data) that functions in a similar way a sub-menu would, with a simple hover script.

Answer (score 0):

Using standards is usually best practice. So my favorite replacement object for the `select` tag is nothing.

Using anything else will most likely cause cross-browser problems, poor usability on mobile devices and general confusion for the end user.